# Make a "Loved" or favorite podcasts playlist?

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts, playlist

I really have been trying to find a way to save my favorite podcast episodes from different channels into one playlist. With the new Love button in iTunes, I made a Smart Playlist using this feature. But no luck  iTunes wasn't updating the Smart Playlist with any podcasts that I marked as Loved. Any ideas? Maybe this functionality isn't possible with iTunes? If so, that's a shame...

Thanks

[image: Smart playlist settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

## For podcasts

For podcasts, this worked for me:

[image]

I noticed, you must add the podcast through the right-click menu also:

[image]

Comment: I know about songs, my question was about podcasts. :) Right, I think I did add it through the right-click menu, but it didn't seem to update at all or ever. There was an update for iTunes recently (12.2.1), maybe I'll try again.

Comment: @jaminroe Maybe live updating is off?

Comment: So I made the playlist again. Before I had the order of the rules like my screenshot above. I switched them around like yours, and its working now! Either that fixed it, or the iTunes update did. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't sync to iOS. Not sure why :( Maybe a bug? Look here: http://i.imgur.com/ts8jLo2.png

Comment: @jaminroe did you make sure the podcasts are syncing with their metadata?

Comment: How would I check that? In iTunes on Mac or Music in iOS? My podcasts work fine in my Podcasts app on iOS.

Comment: @jaminroe I don't use podcasts but my best guess would be is that you can't greate playlists of podcasts on iOS

Comment: Nope, playlists should be under my stations. [info](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5321443?tstart=0)

Comment: Unfortunately, Stations are only to filter podcast stations and new episodes, etc.. You can't save specific episodes in a Station. :( So maybe something they will do someday. Thanks though!